# Flutter Web and firebase initialization error

Tags: flutter, firebase

Since upgrading to Flutter 3.16.9, my Flutter web app with Firebase won't initialise, even with the newest versions. I keep getting this error whenever I run the app.

> Error: I expected a value of type 'String' but got one of type 'Null'

Before the update It worked fine, but now my projects, which I am currently developing are not running either.

My code

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Ive tried multiple different versions even tried downgrading flutter. im just expecting my firebase to initialise correctly and i can carry on with my app which only relies on firebase

Comment: Please post more information about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same issue my web application i solve this issue by adding databaseURL: "" in my firebase_option file.